# Denesting radicals $\sqrt[3]{-22+15\sqrt[3]{3}+9\sqrt[3]{9}}$ and $\sqrt[3]{8-9\sqrt[3]{3}+3\sqrt[3]{9}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I am trying to do denesting radicals:$$\sqrt[3]{-22+15\sqrt[3]{3}+9\sqrt[3]{9}}$$ and $$\sqrt[3]{8-9\sqrt[3]{3}+3\sqrt[3]{9}}$$
I tried to find Ramanujan polynomial like this link [denesting radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710826/use-ramanujan-s-method-to-denest-sqrt37-sqrt320-1-and-sqrt37-sqr/3657659#3657659)

But it doesn't work. I also tried to solve the system of equation $\sqrt[3]{-22+15\sqrt[3]{3}+9\sqrt[3]{9}}=a+b\sqrt[3]{3}+c\sqrt[3]{9}$ but it led to a scary-looking one.

Comment: "*it led to a scary-looking one*" $\;-\;$ Don't let looks scare you. If you carry the calculations through you get the solution $\,a=2, b=-1, c=1\,$.

Comment: Seem scary-looking friend, this is the system of equations after raise power of 3 $a^3+3b^3+9c^3+18abc=-22$,$a^2b+3ac^2+3b^2c=5$,$a^2c+ab^2+3bc^2=3$, how can you solve it? Can you share your ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at finding the minimal polynomial for your numbers and factoring that polynomial? Let $x=-22+15\sqrt[3]{3}+9\sqrt[3]{9}$; then the minimal polynomial is $x^3+66x^2+237x-32768$, so the minimal polynomial of $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is $M(y) = y^9+66y^6+237y^3-32768$. A cubic factor of this is going to have the form $P(y) = y^3+ay^2+by-32$ (since the norm of $x$ is $32768$, the norm of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is $32$) and from here finding $a$ and $b$ should be a little easier.

Comment: I am not good at it, i will try then, i repeat to use Ramanujan's method, but it seems in my problem have many cases or just this method can't be applied. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ be the set of all numbers of the form $a + b\sqrt[3]{3} + c\sqrt[3]{9}$ for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$, and define the function $N(\cdot)$ on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ by

\begin{align*}
N(a + b\sqrt[3]{3} + c\sqrt[3]{9})
&= \prod_{k=0}^{2}(a + b \sqrt[3]{3}\,e^{2\pi i k/3} + c \sqrt[3]{9} \,e^{4\pi i k/3}) \\
&= a^3 + 3b^3 + 9c^3 - 9abc,
\end{align*}

Then it is not hard to check that, for $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$,

$$ N(xy) = N(x)N(y). $$

Now, suppose that $x = \sqrt[3]{-22 + 15\sqrt[3]{3} + 9\sqrt[3]{9}}$ is actually of the form $x = a + b\sqrt[3]{3} + c\sqrt[3]{9}$ for some integers $a, b, c$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
N(x)^3 = N(x^3) &= N(-22 + 15\sqrt[3]{3} + 9\sqrt[3]{9}) = 32768 = 2^{15}
\end{align*}

So, this and the equation $x^3 = -22 + 15\sqrt[3]{3} + 9\sqrt[3]{9}$ together yield

\begin{align*}
a^3 + 3b^3 + 9c^3 - 9abc &= N(x) = 32, \\
a^3 + 3b^3 + 9c^3 + 18abc &= -22, \\
3 a^2b + 9b^2 c + 9ac^2 &= -15, \\
3 ab^2 + 3a^2 c + 9bc^2 &= 9.
\end{align*}

From the first two equations, we get $27abc = -54$, or equivalently, $abc = -2$. This leaves only a handful of cases to be checked, and then it is not hard to find that $(a, b, c) = (2, -1, 1)$.

Generalizing this observation, we get:

> **Observation.** Suppose that rational numbers $a, b, c, A, B, C$ satisfy the equation
> $$ a + b\sqrt[3]{3} + c\sqrt[3]{9} = \sqrt[3]{A + B\sqrt[3]{3} + C\sqrt[3]{9}}. $$
> Then we have
> $$ 27abc = A - \sqrt[3]{A^3 + 3B^3 + 9C^3 - 9ABC}. $$

---

Likewise, assume that $\sqrt[3]{8-9\sqrt[3]{3}+3\sqrt[3]{9}} = a + b\sqrt[3]{3} + c\sqrt[3]{9}$ for some integers $a, b, c$. Then by the observation above, we get

$$ 27abc = 8 - \sqrt[3]{512} = 0 $$

and hence at least one of $a, b, c$ is zero. Indeed, when $b = 0$, we are led to solve the system of equations

\begin{align*}
a^3 + 9c^3 &= 8, &
9ac^2 &= -9, &
3a^2c &= 3.
\end{align*}

The last two equations shows that $c = -a$, and then the first equation gives $-8a^3 = 8$, hence $ a = -1$ and $c = 1$. Therefore $(a, b, c) = (-1, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using Wolfram Alpha:

[WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-22%2B15%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3%7D%2B9%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B9%7D):
$\alpha=-22+15\sqrt[3]{3}+9\sqrt[3]{9}$ is a root of $f(x)=x^3 + 66 x^2 + 237 x - 32768$.

[WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E3+%2B+66+x%5E2+%2B+237+x+-+32768+where+x%3Dt%5E3):
$f(x^3)=(x^3 - 6 x^2 + 21 x - 32) (x^6 + 6 x^5 + 15 x^4 + 62 x^3 + 249 x^2 + 672 x + 1024)$.

This suggests that the (real) cubic root of $\alpha$ is a root of $g(x)=x^3 - 6 x^2 + 21 x - 32$, because the other factor is irreducible and has degree 6 and we expect the answer to be in the cubic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]3)$.

[WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E3+-+6+x%5E2+%2B+21+x+-+32%3D0):
the only real root of $g$ is $\beta= 2 - \sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt[3]{9}$.

[WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282+-+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B9%7D%29%5E3):
it easy to check that $\beta^3=\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you, seem impossible to solve by hand.

Comment: I am fascinated by your answer and also confused.  Analytically, why couldn't the (real) cubic root of $\alpha$ be one of the roots of $$(x^6 + 6 x^5 + 15 x^4 + 62 x^3 + 249 x^2 + 672 x + 1024) = 0 ~? $$

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  My total ignorance of Field Theory is showing.  Your response is illuminating.  No point in my delving further, unless and until I plow through a Field Theory book.

Answer (score 1):

(*Too long for a comment.*)

> this is the system of equations after raise power of 3
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> p(a,b,c) = a^3+3b^3+9c^3+18abc+22 &= 0
> \\ q(a,b,c) = a^2b+3ac^2+3b^2c-5 &= 0
> \\ r(a,b,c) = a^2c+ab^2+3bc^2-3 &= 0
> \end{align}
> $$

Not something you'd do by hand, but that's an algebraic system which can always be reduced to one single polynomial equation using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Case_of_two_equations_in_two_unknowns), and then checked for rational solutions using the rational root theorem.

In this case for example, with WA's assistance you get [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28a%5E3%2B3b%5E3%2B9c%5E3%2B18abc%2B22%2C+a%5E2c%2Bab%5E2%2B3bc%5E2-3%2C+a%29) & [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28a%5E2b%2B3ac%5E2%2B3b%5E2c-5%2C+a%5E2c%2Bab%5E2%2B3bc%5E2-3%2C+a%29)
$\to$ [3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28-3b%5E9%2B27b%5E6c%5E3-22b%5E6-81b%5E5c%2B648b%5E3c%5E6-66b%5E3c%5E3-486b%5E2c%5E4-198b%5E2c-243bc%5E2%2B81c%5E9%2B396c%5E6%2B484c%5E3-27%2C3b%5E7c-5b%5E5-18b%5E4c%5E4%2B9b%5E3c%5E2%2B15b%5E2c%5E3%2B9b%5E2%2B27bc%5E7-30bc-27c%5E5%2B25c%5E2%2Cb%29) with the only rational root $c=1\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
u(b,c) = \text{res}_a (p,q) &= -3 b^9 + 27 b^6 c^3 - 22 b^6 - 81 b^5 c + 648 b^3 c^6 - 66 b^3 c^3
\\ &\quad - 486 b^2 c^4 - 198 b^2 c - 243 b c^2 + 81 c^9 + 396 c^6 + 484 c^3 - 27
\\v(b,c) = \text{res}_a(q,r) &= 3 b^7 c - 5 b^5 - 18 b^4 c^4 + 9 b^3 c^2 + 15 b^2 c^3 + 9 b^2 + 27 b c^7
\\ &\quad - 30 b c - 27 c^5 + 25 c^2
\\ w(c) = \text{res}_b(u,v) &= -9 (c - 1) (c^2 + c + 1) (3 c^3 + 1) (9 c^3 - 8) (\small{\dots\text{<degree 63 factor>} \dots})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The last resultant has degree 72 !

Comment: @lhf Emphasis on "*not something you'd do by hand*" ;-)